# how to bind data to flexi grid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, flexigrid

this is my code on my .aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".fgrid").flexigrid({
            url: '../_AJAX/ajaxCall-InterestSubsidy.aspx',            
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'MODE': 'BindFlexiGrid' }),
            colModel: [
                       { display: 'Id', name: 'DistrictId', width: 20, sortable: true, align: 'center' },
                       { display: 'Name', name: 'DistrictName', width: 20, sortable: true, align: 'left' }
                      ],
            sortname: "DistrictName",
            sortorder: "asc",
            usepager: true,
            useRp: true,
            rp: 10,
            width: 700,
            height: 400,
            onSuccess: function()
            { alert('DONE'); }
        });
    });      
</script>
```

This is my Server side code on ajaxCall-InterestSubsidy.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Form["MODE"] != null)
    {
        if (Request.Form["MODE"] == "BindGrid")
        {
            SelectState();
        }
        else if (Request.Form["MODE"] == "BindFlexiGrid")
        {
            SelectState2();
        }
    }
}

public string SelectState2()
{
    DataTable dt= new DataTable();
    try
    {

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        pList = new List<SqlParameter>();
        dt = sa.GetDataTableWithSP("SPSelectDistrictWithSelect", pList);    


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
}
```

Now there are two question:

1. How to pass parameter "MODE" to  ajaxCall-InterestSubsidy.aspx.cs page? so I can    access rigth method
2. Am I missing anything to bind the flexi grid (I am using Newtonsoft.Json dll) ?

Answer (score 0):

Your type `POST` should be `GET`.

You need to return a JSON formatted string that matches your Grid Display.